# Android: Sorting mp3 files by title in a clickable listview

Tags: android, listview, sorting, mp3

I am attempting to create a music player app for a Nexus 7 tablet. I am able to retrieve music files from a specific directory as well as information that is associated with them such as title, artist, etc. I have loaded the files's titles into a clickable list view. When the user clicks on a title, it takes them to an activity that plays the associated song. I was attempting to sort the titles alphabetically and ran into a snag. When I sort just the titles, they no longer match with the correct songs. This is to be expected since I only ordered the titles and not the actual files. I attempted to modify the sorting algorithm by doing this:

```
//will probably only work for Nexus 7
private final static File fileList = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Music/");
private final static File fileNames[] = fileList.listFiles(); //get list of files

public static void sortFiles()
{
    int j;
    boolean flag = true;
    File temp;

    MediaMetadataRetriever titleMMR = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    MediaMetadataRetriever titleMMR2 = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

     while(flag)
     {
         flag = false;

         for(j = 0; j < fileNames.length - 1; j++)
         {
             titleMMR.setDataSource(fileNames[j].toString());
             titleMMR2.setDataSource(fileNames[j+1].toString());

             if(titleMMR.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE).compareToIgnoreCase(titleMMR2.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE)) > 0)
             {
                 temp = fileNames[j];
                 fileNames[j] = fileNames[j+1];     // swapping
                 fileNames[j+1] = temp;
                 flag = true;
             }//end if 
         }//end for
     }//end while
}
```

This is supposed to retrieve the song titles from two files, compare them, and swap the files in the File array if the first comes after the second alphabetically. For some reason, when I run the activity that calls this method, the app crashes. If I remove the **+ 1** from **titleMMR2**'s data source
`titleMMR2.setDataSource(fileNames[j].toString());`

the app no longer crashes but the list is not in order. Again this is understandable since it compares the song titles to themselves. I don't know why the **+ 1** would make the program crash. It is not an array out of bounds error. There are a total of 6 .mp3 files in the directory and they are the only files in that directory. I have also tried using `Arrays.sort(fileNames)` but that only orders them by their file name and not song title. I also tried this:

```
Arrays.sort(fileNames, new Comparator<File>(){
        public int compare(File f1, File f2)
        {
            titleMMR.setDataSource(f1.toString());
            titleMMR2.setDataSource(f2.toString());

            return titleMMR.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE).compareToIgnoreCase(titleMMR2.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE));
        } });
```

That snippet also resulted in a crash. There are no errors in the java code and all appropriate classes have been imported. I'm really at a loss as to what is wrong. Any help will be appreciated and if any new info is needed I will gladly provide it. Thanks in advance.

***FIXED***

The correct code snip is this:

```
public static void sortFiles()
{
    int j;
    boolean flag = true;
    File temp;

    MediaMetadataRetriever titleMMR = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    MediaMetadataRetriever titleMMR2 = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

     while(flag)
     {
         flag = false;

         for(j = 0; j < fileNames.length - 1; j++)
         {
             titleMMR.setDataSource(fileNames[j].toString());
             titleMMR2.setDataSource(fileNames[j+1].toString());

             String title1;
             String title2;

             if(titleMMR.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE) == null)
                 title1 = fileNames[j].getName();
             else
                 title1 = titleMMR.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);

             if(titleMMR2.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE) == null)
                 title2 = fileNames[j+1].getName();
             else
                 title2= titleMMR2.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);

             if(title1.compareToIgnoreCase(title2) > 0)
             {
                 temp = fileNames[j];
                 fileNames[j] = fileNames[j+1];     // swapping
                 fileNames[j+1] = temp;
                 flag = true;
             }//end if 
         }//end for
     }//end while
}
```

Comment: What was the error in the log cat when you tried with the custom Comparator and it crashed?

Comment: I run the app through the Nexus 7 tablet. After the apk is compiled I quit the emulator and load it to the tablet. I don't know of a way to simulate the file system with Eclipse so as a result I don't have any error messages. I thought that since I was using files on the tablet to get the info, the emulator wouldn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience, I found my problem. It was not within any of the code. One of my mp3s did not have a title set. I did not account for this and was trying to pull a title that didn't exist. I will edit the OP to fix it.